# Linq Help please.. Direct casting to Object instead of Var

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I've always ignored the need for LINQ by iterating over objects but recently decided its time to leave behind the old school methods and get with the times.

I'm wondering if someone can help me simplify the below code by firstly, using Lambda instead of old school Linq and secondly, the below code will always return only 1 value.. How can I cast directly to the correct type (Player) in this case without having to iterate again?

```
    MyEntities entity = new MyEntities();

    Guid selectedPlayerID = Guid.Parse(lbPlayers.SelectedItem.Value);


    var player = from n in entity.Players
                 where n.ID == selectedPlayerID
                 select n;

    foreach (var item in player)
    {
        tbPlayerSurname.Text = item.Name;
        tbPlayerName.Text = item.Surname;    
    }
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. That was super fast and great answers... 14 minutes from posting to a solution.. You can't buy a support contract like that anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If entity.Players contain Player objects you can simply specify

```
IEnumerable<Player> players = entity.Players
.Where(p => p.ID == selectedPlayerID);
```

I was having trouble understanding your post so my initial answer was to actually select only one (and reading comments i see that is what you wanted) which you could do like this:

```
Player player = entity.Players.Single(p => p.ID == selectedPlayerID);
```

This throws and error if there are not excatly one, you could use SingleOrDefault and check for null, or even FirstOrNull, in which case you risk swallowing a potential error if there were more than one and that is supposed to get caught

Comment: Note that if you are certain that it **will** return value, you should use ``Single`` and let the CLR throw the exception for you in case more/less than 1 result is returned.

Comment: I'm certain that it will always return a value and only 1.. The ID column is a Primary key column on a table which GUIDs

Comment: I updated my answer based on your comment, if anyone cares ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
var blahs = entity.Players.Where(x => x.ID == selectedPlayerID)
                  .Select(x => new blah() { Name = x.Name, Text = x.Surname);
```

This gives you an `IEnumerable<Blah>`.

Does it make sense?

Comment: Thanks Erik. This offers another way to do it, but the solution from Per Hornshøj-Schierbeck works best for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
entity.Players.Single(n=>n.ID==selectedPlayerId);
```

if you think it might not exist use SingleOrDefault (and check the return value being different from default, null in case of classes).
if you care only about the first one use First or FirstOrDefault instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code below if **entity.Players** is of type **List<Player>**

```
List<Player> selectedPlayers = (from n in entity.Players 
                                where n.ID == selectedPlayerID select n).ToList();
```

And if **entity.Players** is not of type **List<Player>**

```
List<Player> selectedPlayers = (from n in entity.Players 
                               where n.ID == selectedPlayerID 
                               select new Player() { Name = n.Name, Surname = n.Surname } );
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Yeah, entity.Players contains Player Objects.. The easist solution for me is : Player player = ent.Players.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ID == selectedPlayerID);
I should've mentioned that the entity contains the strongly typed objects.

Comment: Its fine. Happy Coding.. We can learn a lot from lots of answers.. That's the best part here in StackOverflow..